# How to Integrate spree and jirafe?

Tags: ruby, spree

I tried alot of ways to install(integrate) my spree with jirafe on my localhost but all failed can anyone explain me the step by step process to integrate jirafe with spree

Comment: Please explain at least one of your attempts in more detail, and show what went wrong, e.g. error message, unexpected results.

Comment: @NeilSlater nothing went wrong. This was a question for getting started. Which is valid considering Jirafe's mixed messages to developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use [Jirafe's Ruby Client](https://github.com/jirafe/jirafe-ruby-client) where @radar can't even submit a PR. Try using [Jirafe's Ruby](https://github.com/jirafe/jirafe-ruby) which has 20x less commits (63 for jirafe-ruby-client and 3 for jirafe-ruby).

Jirafe's support for ruby may be slightly concerning, therefore, I would recommend using Google Analytics.

You can read in [more detail here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spree-user/xymiYIr2LqA) my accidental rant on Jirafe and why you may want to use Google Analytics. I'm pretty sure Spree Analytics is a wrapper for the GA, but I may be wrong on that.